# Unable to lookup JNDI with Weblogic 12.1.2 + Spring 4.1.9.RELEASE+Hibernate 4.3.11.Final

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, jndi

I upgraded my application to **`Spring v4.1.9.RELEASE`** and **`Hibernate v4.3.11.Final`** versions and upgraded to **`Weblogic 12.1.2`** too, after that I am facing the **`JNDI`** lookup issue.

Error Stack:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/xxxxx]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up /comp.env.jdbc.xxxxx in /app/webapp/xxxxx/1037358259.; remaining name '/comp/env/jdbc/xxxxx'
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1180)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ApplicationNamingNode.lookup(ApplicationNamingNode.java:143)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:253)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:426)
    at weblogic.jndi.factories.java.ReadOnlyContextWrapper.lookup(ReadOnlyContextWrapper.java:45)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.AbstractURLContext.lookup(AbstractURLContext.java:135)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:415)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:114)
    ... 73 more
```

The JNDIs I configured are correct and I tried changing the jndi from **java:comp/env/jdbc/xxxx** to **jdbc/xxxx**  but still on the same page.

Can you please help...

**--Update--**
I changed my datasource xml file from **java:comp/env/jdbc/xxxx**  to **jdbc/xxxx** from code side not from the JNDI config in the admin console, in the admin console it was **jdbc/xxxx** and finally it worked.

Thanks

Comment: Can somebody please help?

Comment: could you add your spring-jdbc configuration xml along with the jndi data source you defined in the admin console?

Comment: for datasource configuration, you can paste the xml you're using under <domain_name>config/jdbc